# Create custom role in Azure AD as owner

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

So I'm trying to create custom roles in Azure AD for an Asp.net mvc5 web app. I did a lot of reading up, but basically it fails due to lack of auth. I issue the PowerShell command `New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile myNewRole.json` but it fails saying that my (current logged on user) *does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinition/write" over scope...*

Well, the error message is clear. At the same time, if I list my user's roles I am 'owner'. What privileges is needed to create custom roles in Azure AD if owner doesn't suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in your assignable scopes section can you confirm that there aren't any typos and the scope is your subscription GUID.  We have come across this scenario where there was something awry with the scopes section.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. Talk about confusing error messages from Azure. Well, it makes sense I guess, since the assignable scope I had specified was 'out of my league'. Anyways, now it works perfectly. Brilliant, thanks again.